# Temporarily set Matplotlib backend for one cell, reverting afterwards

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter, ipython

Normally when using IPython + Jupyter + Matplotlib, I choose a [Matplotlib backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html) using the [`%matplotlib` magic in IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib).

However, sometimes I want to change to a different backend for one specific cell, and then immediately revert to the backend that I was using before. For example, I sometimes want to use the `widget` backend for a single plot, but I don't want to have it active for the rest of my notebook.

I could of course put `%matplotlib widget` at the top of the cell and then `%matplotlib inline` at the bottom of the cell, but is there a nicer solution? Either using a single "temporary" `%matplotlib` magic (happy to write my own if it's not complicated), or using a context manager.

Is it as simple as this, or is there more to it?

```py
@contextmanager
def mpl_backend(backend):
    original = matplotlib.get_backend()
    yield matplotlib.use(backend)
    matplotlib.use(original)
```